# Pubnub herenow not returning UUID list

Tags: java, javascript, publish-subscribe, pubnub

I have recently started looking into pubnub, and I am trying to make pub-sub application using the same. I have my publisher in java and Subscriber in javascript.

Following is the publisher code in java:

```
Pubnub pubnub = new Pubnub("pub-c-key", "sub-c-key");
pubnub.hereNow("my_channel", cb);
```

In my Callable for hereNow I did a Sysout for response and i get the following response:

```
{"message":"OK","status":200,"uuids":[],"service":"Presence","occupancy":0}
```

Here is my JS code:

```
<script src=http://cdn.pubnub.com/pubnub.min.js ></script>
<script>(function(){

 var pubnub = PUBNUB.init({
     publish_key   : 'pub-c-key',
     subscribe_key : 'sub-c-key'
 });

 pubnub.subscribe({
     channel : "my_channel",
     message : function(m){ document.getElementById("my_item").innerHTML = m; },
     connect : publish
 });

 function publish() {
     pubnub.publish({
         channel : "my_channel",
         message : "Connected!"
     });
 }

})();</script>
```

But when I publish something to the channel, I get the result displayed on the webpage where the script is executed. `pubnub.publish("my_channel","Offer!" , callback);`

Why is the hereNow not working in my case? Any help or lead would do. I have read the pubnub documentation but I couldn't get it.

Comment: Can you check if you have the Presence feature enabled on your key. Check admin.pubnub.com

Comment: I just found that out. I did not know that I have to enable it separately for each app-key pair..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured out that we had to enable Presence feature for each key on the PubNub dashboard for this to work. Silly thing I missed out..

Comment: Do you know what I have to activate to know if user is typing or not?